Expo app won't build for ios after updating to Xcode 16.1
Everything was working fine until I updated my Xcode to 16.1.
Build fails with:
⚠️  ld: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
⚠️  ld: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
⚠️  ld: Could not parse or use implicit file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUICore.framework/SwiftUICore.tbd': cannot link directly with 'SwiftUICore' because product being built is not an allowed client of it
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
┌─ Symbol: absl::lts_20240116::CHexEscape(absl::lts_20240116::string_view)
└─ Referenced from: grpc_core::StatusToString(absl::lts_20240116::Status const&)::$_0::operator()(absl::lts_20240116::string_view, absl::lts_20240116::Cord const&) const in grpc[737](status_helper.o)


❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

and
2 error(s), and 32 warning(s)

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I've tried clearing pods and reinstalling, deleting xcode derived data, reinstalling node modules, now I don't know what to do to get this app working.

I managed to fix my build issue by updating my packages to latest version. Maybe one of them wasn't supporting the new Xcode 16.1

My build fails too and I get this error:
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-debug' from project 'Pods')


--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C96C50E3-D440-4AA7-8097-E9249B002D0C, OS:18.1, name:iPhone 16 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C96C50E3-D440-4AA7-8097-E9249B002D0C, OS:18.1, name:iPhone 16 Pro Max }
** BUILD FAILED **

Not sure if this is related

Do you think this is an answer or?
